# Is there an alternative to NtQuerySystemInformation for SystemKernelVaShadowInformation and SystemSpeculationControlInformation?

Tags: c++, winapi, spectre

As NtQuerySystemInformation is not encouraged to be used by Microsoft, I am looking for alternatives to display spectre and meltdown mitigation options set on the OS.

Comment: encouraged and so what ? in what problem use *NtQuerySystemInformation* for this

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation for [NtQuerySystemInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation) explains:

> Applications should use the alternate functions listed in this topic.

Neither the [SystemKernelVaShadowInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation#systemkernelvashadowinformation) entry, nor the [SystemSpeculationControlInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation#systemspeculationcontrolinformation) entry list alternate functions, so there is nothing you can do to avoid calling `NtQuerySystemInformation` while still using the functionality it offers.